# TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes (bitmap saving)

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to save an image I created with PIL.Image.new(). The image was opened in "RGB" mode, and I assigned various values into pixels in the image through image.load(). When I try to save the image to file with image.save(filename, 'BMP') however this gives the error TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes. I've seen similar problems with text manipulation from file, however this is not from file: the data is generated at run time. Also nothing related to images. What do I do???

Code:

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open(filename)

newImg = Image.new("RGB", (image.width, image.height))

pixels = newImg.load()

for j in range(image.height):
    for i in range(image.width):
        RGB = image.getpixel((i, j))

        newPixel = []

        for k in range(3):
            newPixel.append(RGB[k])

        pixels[i, j] = tuple(newPixel)

newImg.save(newFilename, 'BMP')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please add a minimal, complete and verifiable source code example of your problem, so we can help you. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: It sounds like you've corrupted your Image object. You need to post a [mcve] that shows the process you use to "assign various values into pixels in the image".

Comment: I've added the code used

Comment: I found the error; the problem was that I was using a TextIOWrapper object as an input for the filename parameter instead of a string, headache over :D